# How to find a particular block of text in all files recursively and append it

Tags: ubuntu

I want to find a particular block of text using **pattern** in all files present in a given folder recursively and append it to the end a file(say file.txt).

Consider the following scenario:

I have a folder which contains multiple folders and xml files and each internal folder contains xml files.

I want to send all code of a particular tag in all files in to a file. The pattern is as follows

```
                     <tag-name  .... </tag-name>
```

Even a file contains same tag name several times, all has to append in to the file.txt.

```
                      command >> file.txt
```

**EDIT** : Any tool can be used.

Comment: `find . -name '*.xml' -exec xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m //tag-name {} + >file.txt` perhaps?

Comment: I support recommendation by tripleee, i.e. not to use grep for this or for any kind of robust and reliable XML processing. Please state in your question whether you are required to use grep or can also use other tools.

Comment: A somewhat tool-unspecific solution for this would be using any available XSL transformer tool with a tailored but quite simple XSLT and a little `find` glue similar to tripleees proposal.

Comment: Just to let you know @tripleee, I referenced your comment, without addressing you personally.

Comment: Yeah, the comment facility is kind of wacky in that way.